# C++ BITMAP to C# Bitmap

Tags: c#, c++, bitmap

I am trying to create a simple screenshare program, with a C++ server, and a C# client. I am currently trying to achieve this by sending the buffer you get from `BitBlt`, and sending that over the net. This all seems to go alright, but when I try to read the buffer in my C# client, the image looks messed up. An example:  [image]

The code I'm using to get the buffer on the C++ end (Found this code somewhere):

```
void ScreenCap()
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL), hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC (hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ScreenX, ScreenY);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = {0};
    bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.biBitCount = 24;
    bmi.biWidth = ScreenX;
    bmi.biHeight = -ScreenY;
    bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    int res = GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, ScreenY, ScreenData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
}
```

Code I'm using to display the image on the C# end:

```
char[] buffer = packet.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(clientWidth, clientHeight);
BitmapData bData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, clientWidth, clientHeight), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
Marshal.Copy(Helper.toByteArray(buffer), 0, bData.Scan0, buffer.Length);
bitmap.UnlockBits(bData);

pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
}));
```

I honestly have no idea whats going on.

EDIT

Some additional information:

Screen Width: 1366 (Both in client and the server)

Screen Height: 768 (Also both the same, in client and server)

For the buffer size, I am simply just using width * height * 3, in this case its 3147264

Comment: Looks like a pixel is being added to each line.

Comment: Out of the blue: You are reading your bitmap in C++ as 24 bit RGB but in C# you are using the default pixel format which is 32bpp. Could you post the values of `buffer.Length`, `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`? And also there might be some confusion: sizeof(char) in C++ is guaranteed to be 1, in .NEt its usually 2.

Comment: You can take screenshot from C# code. If that's an option, see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79efecc4-fa6d-4078-afe4-bb1379bb968b/print-screen-in-c#053a8b99-da28-444a-a342-4e8922aa727f)

Comment: Yes Muepe, give me one second. I'll add them to the question. EDIT Added them to the question

Comment: According to MSDN's BITMAPINFOHEADER `Height` determines if the bitmap is bottom-up (negative) or top-down (positive). You currently have `bmi.biHeight = -ScreenY;`. You may want to try with a positive value.

Comment: TyCobb, removing the - flips the image upside down

Comment: @Muepe About the chars being 2 bytes, I wrote a simple function that converts the char array to a byte array by using 

public static byte[] toByteArray(char[] array)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[array.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                buffer[i] = (byte)array[i];
            return buffer;
        }

Comment: Try this once: `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(clientWidth, clientHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);`

Comment: @Muepe This fixed it :D Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C++-Code you have: `bmi.biBitCount = 24;` but in C# you use the default pixelformat for the bitmap. This is `PixelFormat32bppArgb`. That means that it uses 32 bits per pixel. If you use

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(clientWidth, clientHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

This might fix the problem.